# Python ERROR while using Big Huge Thesaurus API

Tags: python, json

I'm building a synonym program in python.
I have the API_KEY, I'm able to get JSON output

But for some words like 'ABRIGATE' and many more, I get this error on terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "word_power.py", line 26, in <module>
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Also on looking up with the urlin browser gives me a blank page.

```
http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/------API_KEY------/abrigate/json
```

I guess I'm not able to detect if the JSON result exists or not.

The code with I'm checking is:

```
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)

        data = json.load(json_obj)

        if not data:
            print 'Empty'

        if 'noun' not in data:
            print 'NO NOUN'
            #target.write(" ]\n\n");

        if 'verb' not in data:
            print 'NO VERB'
            #target.write(" ]\n\n")

        if 'adjective' not in data:
            print 'NO ADJECTIVE'
            #target.write(" ]\n\n")
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch those instance where the API returns an error:

```
data = None
try:
   json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
   data = json.load(json_obj)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
   if e.code == '404':
      print('Entry not found for URL {}'.format(final_url))
   else:
      print('Got {} - {} for URL {}.'.format(e.code, e.msg, final_url))
```

You can also improve your checking logic:

```
for key,value in data.items():
  print('Word type is: {}'.format(key))
  for prop, values in value.items():
     print('\t{} : {}'.format(prop, ','.join(values)))
```